# About contractible implies simply connected

Tags: general-topology

most books say that contractible implies simply connected is trivial as at time one, every point of the space is shrunk to one point, including the loop. However, there is a problem. In discussing simply connectedness, we use loop homotopy, i.e. we have to ensure the paths in between is also a loop with the same basepoint. But i there no way to guarantee that by contractible condition?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *is there no way,,,

Comment: What is it you're asking exacly?

Comment: This question has already been asked and answered: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266153/contractible-and-simply-connected

Comment: @ZelosMalum: It is quite clear what is being asked (see the link in my earlier comment). However, it is a duplicate.